# How to do the max pooling based on absolute value size for both positive and negative values in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

I want to implement a max pooling method that doesn't only consider the positive value but also inlcude the negative value based on their absolute value sizes.

Here is an example I want to achieve:

let say we have a 3D vector like this:

```
tf.Tensor(
[[[      2     100       1]
  [      7       4       1]]

 [[      5       3       1]
  [     15      11       1]]

 [[   1000     323       1]
  [-100000     231       1]]], shape=(3, 2, 3), dtype=int32)
```

I want to do the max pooling by reducing the second dimension (axis=1), which is similar to

```
tf.reduce_max(vector, axis=1).
```

But I also want to consider the negative values, such that the data I expect to get would look like this:

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 3), dtype=int32, numpy=
array([[   7,  100,    1],
       [  15,   11,    1],
       [-100000,  323,    1]], dtype=int32)>
```

Because -100000 has higher absolute value compared with 1000, so the algorithm will select it.

Could anyone help me to figure out how to do it with **tensorflow**? Thank you so much!